# rabbitmq - custom config file - disk_free_limit not set properly

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, app-config, configuration-files

I've properly install (rpm based) a rabbitmq cluster (with clusterer plugin) in rhel7, create the "custom" configuration files:

/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.config => env varialble

/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config => rabbitmq properties

The rabbitmq cluster works fine exept that **my parameters are ignored,** any idea why?

Thanks in advance for you help

kr,

O.

nb: if I set the paramertesr myself with a command like:

> rabbitmqctl set_disk_free_limit "1g"

for the disk limit for example, it works but I want them to survive a "reboot" :/

Here are my configurations files:

```
# /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.config
(..)
NODE_PORT=5672
NODENAME=rabbit@node1
RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
(..)


cat << EOF > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
[
{kernel, [
     ]},
{rabbit, [
    {cluster_nodes, ["rabbit@node1", "rabbit@node2", "rabbit@node3"], disc}
    {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
    {disk_free_limit, "1GB"},
    {collect_statistics_interval, 10000},
    {heartbeat, 30},
    {cluster_partition_handling, autoheal},
    {default_user, <<"guest">>},
    {default_pass, <<"guest">>}
    ]},

{rabbitmq_clusterer, [
    {config, [ {version,1}, {nodes,["rabbit@node1", "rabbit@node2", "rabbit@node3"]} ]}
    ]}
]
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a little update for this topic, I had misconfigured my rabbitmq files; in order to have a working configuration, do the following modifications.
kr,
O.

- For the environment file: we can **get rid of the '.config'** part in the file name as rabbitMQ add it anyway.
  I my log file, I Had an error with "... /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config.config ... "

So **keep the file with** the .config extension *(/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config)* by set the **env variable without** the .config:

```
(..)
RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
(..)
```

- For the rabbit.config file: As I used the *clusterer* plugins, we can get rid of the line cluster_nodes.

Your file will look like this one:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
[
{kernel, [
     ]},
{rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
    {disk_free_limit, "1GB"},
    {collect_statistics_interval, 10000},
    {heartbeat, 30},
    {cluster_partition_handling, autoheal}
    ]},
{rabbitmq_management, [
    {http_log_dir,"/myapps/myproject/rabbitmq/logs"},
    {listener, [{port, 15672 }]}
    ]},
{rabbitmq_clusterer, [
    {config, [ {version,1}, {nodes,["rabbit@node01", "rabbit@node02", "rabbit@node03"]} ]}
    ]}
].
EOF
```

To verify your current config for the clusterer plugin you can use:

```
 rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_clusterer:status().'
```